# Matrix-vector representation for a system of ODE's

Tags: calculus, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am aiming to explicitly write the matrix-vector representation of this system: 
$$\begin{aligned}y'_1 &= 5y_2 - y_1 + y_3\\
y_2' &= 3y_1 - y_2 + t^2\\
y_3' &= y_3 - ty_2\end{aligned}$$

This is what I have so far:
$\left[\begin{matrix}y_1'\\ y_2'\\y_3'\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}-1 & \;\;5 &\; 1\\ \;\;\;3 & -1 & \;0 \\ \;\;\;0 & \;\;? &\; 1
 \end{matrix}\right]\cdot \left[\begin{matrix}0\\t^2\\?\end{matrix}\right]$

Just not sure how to attack  $-ty_2.$
Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: is it t2 as $t^2$?

Comment: yes t^2 is the value

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Just set 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
y'_1\\
y'_2\\
y'_3
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&5&1\\
3&-1&0\\
0&-t&1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{array}
\right)+
\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
t^2\\
0
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: If you dont mind me asking do you use software to insert formulas in the forum?

Comment: all is here, and you can visit http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1 , but also don't be afraid to press the edit button and see how anyone can write with $\LaTeX$

Comment: @Simon - a quick way to display a vector is `\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}` which renders to $$\pmatrix{x \\ y \\z}$$ In all honesty, find posts with math, right click on them and select show math as TeX. This is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following system of odes:

$\begin{align*}
y_1'&= -y_1+5y_2+y_3\\
y_2'&=3y_1-y_2+t^2\\
y_3'&=y_3-ty_2
\end{align*}$

Then make $u=\begin{bmatrix} y_1&y_2&y_3 \end{bmatrix}^T$ and you get

$$u'= \begin{bmatrix}-1&5&1\\ 3&-1&0\\ 0&-t&1 \end{bmatrix}u+ \begin{bmatrix}0\\t^2\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$